# Running the database connection from android studio emulator to android apps on cell phones

Tags: android, database, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

I have connected my database through the phpmyadmin for android studio and it is working perfectly when use the code 10.0.3.2 in task.execute() function instead of localhost for genymotion emulator in adroid studio. But when i build the APK file for the same and transfer it to my android cell phone the app fails to read the database. What Can be done? 
Here is the code for the main java class file that is being used.
Sorry for not providing it earlier

***Java Class file code***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements    AsyncResponse, View.OnClickListener{

EditText etUsername, etPassword;
Button btnLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etUsername= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    etPassword= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnLogin=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void processFinish(String result) {
    if(result.equals("success")){
        Intent in = new Intent(this,SubActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    HashMap postData = new HashMap();
    postData.put("mobile", "android");
    postData.put("txtUsername", etUsername.getText().toString());
    postData.put("txtPassword", etPassword.getText().toString() );

    PostResponseAsyncTask task= new PostResponseAsyncTask(this, postData);
    task.execute("http://10.0.3.2/client/login.php");

}
```

}

Comment: Please share your code/workaround

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your problem correctly, you need to use the address of your computer in the network like: http://192.168.1.8